# Launch statistics in Android

Tags: android, launching-application, usage-statistics

Is there any way to get statistics about other application launches in Android system?

Specifically I have the following questions:

- How many times other applications was launched?
- How much time user spent in other applications?

Is there any API for getting such kind of information in Android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can add google analytics or the like utilities to your application but you cannot sniff what other people do with their own unless they publish such data.